# why is there just no file?

Tags: command-line

[image]

I am trying to download this video and for some reason the file just doesn't appear to exist though when i try to re-download it, youtube-dl says that it already exists?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're doing, but check the name, `youtube-dl` . It is not `/home/atti` but `/home/atti/home/atti/`

Comment: How does this have anything to do with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

Use different path:

```
ls -la /home/atti/home/atti/MOVIES
```